# Use Ruby to read in uncompressed video file

Tags: ruby

I need to create a script to read in an uncompressed video file, sample a frame every 1/2 second, and output a bitmap. I would need to do this in Ruby.

I am having an issue starting out. Is there a package that I can use to handle the metadata in the video file? Any suggestions on what format video file I should use?

Comment: "and output a bitmap" you mean you want to extract frames every half second and create an image?

Comment: yes. I basically want to create a programmable number of bitmap images (frame) from a video file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `ffmpeg` pretty much all the time when working with video data, so if you have access to it then you can try any of the ruby interfaces available such as [streamio-ffmpeg](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg)

If you're unable to find a ruby gem that is compatible with your environment, and you must (or prefer to) use Ruby, then you may consider making system calls directly depending on your needs.

Comment: The problem with this is I am running on Windows AND I am using 1.8.6 version of Ruby which is incompatible with streamio-ffmpeg. Is there an older package or a native way for me to take screenshots of the movie file?

Comment: There are Windows binaries for ffmpeg as well. There are many tutorials on how to extract frames.

Comment: Thanks MxyL. I used ffmpeg and got it to do exactly what I wanted!